# Issues in running Jmeter amfproxy

Tags: java, apache-flex, jmeter, amf, jmeter-plugins

Have been trying to do a load test on flash game server that uses **amfPHP** for backend interaction.

I have added the **Jmeter- amf** plugin from Ken(steeltomato) and followed all the steps mentioned in the user guide(https://github.com/steeltomato/jmeter-amf/wiki/User-guide)

But whenever  i start recording using the proxy i get this following error in the log

```
2014/02/18 12:14:11 ERROR - jmeter.JMeter: Uncaught exception: java.lang.NullPointerException   
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.amf.proxy.AmfProxyControl.deliverSampler(AmfProxyControl.java:433)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.amf.proxy.AmfProxy.run(AmfProxy.java:315)
2014/02/18 12:14:13 ERROR - jmeter.JMeter: Uncaught exception:  java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.amf.proxy.AmfProxyControl.deliverSampler(AmfProxyControl.java:433)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.amf.proxy.AmfProxy.run(AmfProxy.java:315)
```

The line error seems to be that of an event that could not capture the value since this happens every time i load a page to capture.

Did i miss out something in the steps or is it because of any **Jmeter** restrictions. I could not find the *amf sampler* type in **Jmeter** is this what cause the error?

Comment: hi, in the latest Amfphp there's a profiler, so maybe you don't need to use Jmeter http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/documentation/using-the-back-office/profiler/ You can use it together with the call repeater in the service browser, so that covers most load testing use cases. http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/documentation/using-the-back-office/service-browser/

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply, been through the links provided. Do you think we can initiate a VUScenario with the same?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with VUScenario? The call repeater has only one setting, the amount of concurrent users, so it's quite basic. If you need something more sophisticated you'll need another tool. If you have a suggestion on how to improve the call repeater, please share it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the call repeater function is great actually and it makes things a lot easier. By VUScenario I meant about the possibility of pushing several concurrent calls from several machines. 

Dont know how foolish I am but I think it would be great if we can access BackOffice call repeater from a tool(say Jmeter) so that we can create a setup where we can have a Jmeter server and agents making concurrent calls to the services.

Comment: sounds fun but I wouldn't know where to begin. In the meantime you can run the call repeater in 2 separate browsers, it would be a start.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you are trying to use does not work with recent up to date versions of JMeter.

I think you need to use JMeter < 2.6 which is now very old.

An alternative is to use this commercial plugin which is maintained and provides more features than the one you tried, see:

- https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/ubikloadpack-flex-amf-plugin-4-0-for-apache-jmeter-released/
- https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/load-testing-flex-with-jmeter-made-easy/

Disclaimer : We are provider of this plugin