# Unable to record in JMeter using AMF proxy server

Tags: flash, github, jmeter, amf

I have downloaded amf plugins as given in [How to enable amf sampler type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770078/how-to-enable-amf-sampler-type)
and started recording using AMF proxy server in Jmeter 4.0 but I am getting below error message in log and web page is not loading

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
        org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSampler2
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.amf.proxy.AmfDaemon.run(AmfDaemon.java:125) ~[JMeter-AMF.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler2
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking into commit [`2651c6ffc534e0137849377fce4b1b0e1aafca47`](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1783280) the file `src/protocol/http/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSampler2.java` has been removed as a part of [issue 60727](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60727) during [JMeter 3.2 release](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html)

So the maximum version you can use AMF Proxy Server with is [JMeter 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-31).

You can still download JMeter 3.1 from [JMeter Archives](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/) page

Answer (score 1):

As per Dmitri Answer the plugin you're trying to use only works with JMeter <= 3.1 due to drop of HTTPSampler2 within removal of commons-httpclient-3.x in JMeter. JMeter 3.1 which is now very old (3 versions away) and suffers from 2 CVEs in distributed testing.

Also see this:

- [Issues in running Jmeter amfproxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847658/issues-in-running-jmeter-amfproxy)

Your alternative is to use this [commercial plugin](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/ubikloadpack-flex-amf-plugin-4-0-for-apache-jmeter-released/) for JMeter which works with latest version including 4.0, it works with BlazeDS only , not GraniteDS.

Disclaimer: we are providers of this plugin.